# Errors in Extension Library Demo db

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am getting an error when I try to display pages from the xpage Extension Library demo.

Cannot find the library "com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library" with tag version 8.5.32001, to be used by the page /Core_Dialog.xsp. The library tag version is blank.

If I use extenstion library controls in my own db on the same server then they work fine.  In fact I display the version number on the welcome page of most of my apps. It displays ExtLib Version: 8.5.3.20111208-0717

Any idea why the deo would not work?

I have downloaded the latest copy of the demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the latest copy of the demo you also need to use the latest version of ExtLib which is 20121217.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I was thinking that the demos would be backward compatible for the existing controls in the version of the Ext Lib that I have but I guess it makes sense that they limit by version.